# get rid of NAs in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get rid of #NAs in excel, I've tried using the VLOOKUP formula but it doesn't seems to be working in my case. I just have one cell from A1:A18, and two of the cells contains NAs, I was wondering what the VLOOKUP formula would be like to get rid of those cells.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula `=IFNA(A1,"")` in an adjacent column and copy downwards. The second argument of this function is the value that you want to replace a cell containing `#N/A` with. I've chosen a blank string, but you could use 0, &c.

On older versions of Excel (prior to the 2013) release, use `=IF(ISNA(A1), "", A1)`

Then perform the rest of your analysis on that newly created column.

I dislike removing the `#N/A` cells as that can destroy the structure of your workbook, and using VBA to remove them is inherently buggy since `#N/A` propagates through built-in Excel functions.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

1. Select `A1:A18`
2. Run the following:

   ```
   Sub InsertIFERROR()

       Dim R As Range

       For Each R In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
           R.Formula = "=IFNA(" & Mid(R.Formula, 2) & ","""")"
       Next R

   End Sub
   ```
3. It is a bit dangerous, because you will not see #NA errors and you cannot revert the formulas with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Nice idea, but beware of odd behaviour caused by #N/A propagating through built-in functions.

Comment: @Tom - I simply have this snippet and I use it rarely. `IFNA` is also a good option, indeed.